# Prevent external assembly injection via PublicKeyToken

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, assemblies, code-injection

I'm using the following code:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad += (sender, args) =>
{
    var token = args.LoadedAssembly.GetName().GetPublicKeyToken();

    if (!IsValidToken(token))
    {
        Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
    }
};
```

Where `IsValidToken()` compares the public key token of the assembly being loaded against a list of authorized public key tokens hardcoded in my application as byte arrays.

Is this a good security measure to prevent code injection attacks? Also, is this necessary given the fact that I will later obfuscate my application using NetReactor? I'm trying to prevent any "snooping" into my application, not only coming from the Snoop tool, but from any external undesired sources as well.

Comment: You'll have a hard time trying to figure out the perfect and future-proof authorized list of valid tokens. You may have undesired side-effects for your valid users (like the problems with copy-protected CDs that were a problem only for those who bought it...). At the same time, a good hacker will disassemble the whole thing, and just patch that code with nops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just from first glance, I'm going to say "no, this won't be enough".

Reasons:

- `CreateRemoteThread` attacks are straight win32 calls, no managed code traces that would trip a detector like this
- I think it would be possible to create another `AppDomain` in the injected dll, thus bypassing this check altogether. Then one could execute code from that `AppDomain`, potentially (I'd have to think that through) calling back into the "main" `AppDomain` via `AppDomain.DoCallback`
- `Process.Kill` is a horrible way to drop your application, although it is a non-trappable way of doing so - that is, anyone attached wouldn't be able to prevent it (it uses Win32 `TerminateProcess` under the hood)

I'd have to bust out my "Injecterator" harness to test these statements, tho - if I can remember where the heck I put that code...

Regardless of any of these - you will absolutely want to obfuscate the hell out of this assembly, especially if you plan on storing sensitive bits inside (in fact, I'd argue against storing **ANY** sensitive information inside an assembly if you can help it) - your prevention method will absolutely NOT stop any disassemblers like Reflector, ILSpy, dotPeek, etc.

Comment: What would you recommend as extra security measures? beside obfuscation (which I am already doing) to prevent injection (that causes an application to have unwanted behavior) and intellectual property protection?

Comment: @highcore that depends a lot on your deployment scenario, and what your app is.

Comment: This is part of the `Core` class in my Client/Server application framework, which contains common infrastructure shared by the WCF server part and the WPF client. Applications developed using my framework will be deployed as client/server applications in a LAN environment in my customer's facilities.

Comment: Hmmm...just thinking out loud, but on the managed side, you could trap the Assembly load event and reject anything that wasn't gac' ed/strong named...but preventing injection routes is a different beast. I'd have to think about that - I'm usually dealing with the greyer side of that equation. :)

Answer (score 2):

It would also be safer if you generated the full keys at runtime (perhaps from multiple partial keys). This works around statically examining your binary for keys.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: I would split the keys into 2+ pieces, preferably lightly encrypted -- Rot13 would even work, though I'd recommend something different than Rot13, like Rot11 or Rot17. You then decrypt the pieces and concatenate them together to create the real keys.