# How to prevent Snoop from spying WPF program?

Tags: wpf, snoop

I know Snoop is the open source WPF spying utility, it can help us to spy/browse the visual tree of a running WPF application (without the need for a debugger) … and change properties ... amongst other things.

So it will be very helpful during our development period, it also means somebody else can see our program's inner design.

I don't know if this will be harmful, but I was wondering if there is a way to prevent Snoop from spying our WPF program.

Any ideas?

Comment: I resolved that [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372057/prevent-external-assembly-injection-via-publickeytoken)

Comment: Are you sure after doing that you can prevent snoop from spying, because i have tried what you said, it didn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Snoop proof your wpf application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981959/how-to-snoop-proof-your-wpf-application)